# How would I scrape text from a site?

Tags: download, web-crawler, httrack

Schemer is closing down, and I'm trying to preserve the text because there are many good ideas on the site. I'd like to get the text from within each of the links listed on the [sitemap](https://www.schemer.com/sitemap?lo=1).

Is there a way I can do this? HTTrack isn't working how I'd like it to.

Answer (score 0):

[Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is a classic command-line tool for this kind of task. It comes with most Unix/Linux systems, and you can get it for Windows too.

You’d do something like:

`wget -r --no-parent https://www.schemer.com/sitemap?lo=1`

For more details, see the [Wget Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) and its [examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Examples), or take a look at these:

http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget